# Should a javascript function have optional arguments and also options?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, meteor, arguments

I've been working with the Meteor framework, and I noticed in the documentation that some functions are declared as `function(argument, [options])`, which seems fine. However, others are declared as `function([argument], [options])`. If the argument is optional, shouldn't that mean it is an option?

For example, [`Meteor.absoluteUrl`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_absoluteurl) is defined in the docs like so: `Meteor.absoluteUrl([path], [options])`. The brackets around `[path]` indicate that it doesn't have to be passed, and a default value will be used. However, in the section beneath it:

> ```
> Generate an absolute URL pointing to the application. The server reads from the ROOT_URL environment variable to determine where it is running. This is taken care of automatically for apps deployed with meteor deploy, but must be provided when using meteor bundle.
>
> Arguments
> path String
> A path to append to the root URL. Do not include a leading "/".
>
> Options
> secure Boolean
> Create an HTTPS URL.
>
> replaceLocalhost Boolean
> Replace localhost with 127.0.0.1. Useful for services that don't recognize localhost as a domain name.
>
> rootUrl String
> Override the default ROOT_URL from the server environment. For example: "http://foo.example.com"
> ```

In essence, can someone explain the different between parameters, arguments, options, and optional.

Comment: Please include some code or quality context to your question if you want an upvote from me ;)

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you provide specific examples from Meteor to discuss/comment on.

Comment: Edited. @SufiDeveloper, I don't care about upvotes in the slightest. I want to know the answer.

Comment: @RichLitt It's ok, just don't post crap questions next time if you want answers.

Comment: @SufiDeveloper, please be kinder. This is a community, and asking high level questions can be difficult. Insulting my ability to post a question, where I by definition don't know everything, is not welcoming or friendly. 

I didn't want this to be solely a Meteor question, as I feel it has more to do with Javascript terminology. Meteor was the only example I had, and I figured it was high level enough to be understood without a specific example. I still do.

Comment: @RichLitt People are just tired of low quality questions. Not knowing about a topic doesn't mean you can't put up an **excellent** question, which is what this site is made for. This also isn't a place where we have to hold each other's hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific definition of argument vs. option.  For me, I'd make something an argument over an option when the item is used more commonly or more central to the purpose of the function (even if it is optional).  I'd make something an option when it is one of many settings that can affect the outcome, but the settings would often not be used and are generally not as central to the purpose of the function (even though they have some effect).

In the example you provide, the `[path]` argument is very central to the logic of the function and it will help the readability of the code significantly for that to be shown as an argument and it is likely more commonly used than the options.

---

Optional arguments in Javascript also have some limitations in use.  You can only use optional arguments when it's possible to tell (by examining type or value of the passed arguments), exactly what the callers intent was with the arguments and which argument that was passed is meant to be which argument to the function.

For example, you can't have a function that takes two optional arguments and both are boolean or both are strings.  If only one argument is passed, then you can't tell which of the two optional arguments the caller was intending to pass.  So, sometimes you may pick a set of unambiguous optional arguments (usually with different types) and then put everything else into an options object where each option is named so there is no ambiguity.